# Как сделать поправку на часовой пояс

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, node.js

Почему разница отрицательна и как исправить, я так понимаю нужно поправку сделать на часовой пояс 
сервер работает на ubuntu

отправляю запрос

```
server_time: 1445882661136
time: 1445882657069
index.js:90 Пришли данные о позиции игрока
index.js:95 -4068 это разница
index.js:96 30 это время доставки туда и обратно
```

Время беру так

```
var date = new Date();
date.getTime()
```

Comment: Из приведённого лога неясно что это за числа. 4068 - это 4 только секунды. И часовой пояс не нужен, всё же по Гринвичу должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date.getTime()` возвращает время в UTC, т.е. оно не зависит от часового пояса. Если вы берете время на клиенте раньше чем посылаете запрос на сервер, и время у вас с точностью до мс одинаковое, то клиентское - серверное будет отрицательным. Если нужно серверное время в UTC перевести в какой-либо часовой пояс на клиенте, то:

1. Если часовой пояс, в который нужно перевести, совпадает с часовым поясом в системе пользователя - js сделает это автоматически, т.е. `new Date(setverTime)` внутри себя держит мс, но при выдаче времени - возвращает его в клиентском часовом поясе (если просто вывести в консоль - в конце как раз таки часовой пояс покажет, в котором выводит).
2. Если часовой пояс, в который нужно перевести не совпадает с часовым поясом в системе пользователя и время нужно форматировать для вывода на экран - лучше взять готовую библиотеку http://momentjs.com/timezone/ (а не изобретать велосипеды), она умеет и форматировать и выводить в любом часовом поясе.
3. Если время нужно форматировать всего пару раз - можно воспользоваться `-(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()/60`, который вернет смещение часового пояса в часах, и форматировать время уже вручную.

Это был ответ на вопрос в заголовке, а теперь ответ на вопрос в теле=).

Потому что время на них различается. Даже при наличии авто-обновления времени, никто не гарантирует, что оно будет совпадать с точностью до мс. Собственно учитывая клиентскую машину - полагаться на время с нее (судя по всему для игры многопользовательской) - не самый лучший вариант, т.к. некоторые могут ставить не корректное время (операционки не знающие о всех наших перепитиях с часовыми поясами, зачастую стоят либо с корявым временем, либо с корявым часовым поясом)

Comment: А не подскажете как правильно тогда пинг брать? писал вечером, не заметил что отнимал от клиентского времени вместо серверного =)

Comment: Ну можно как время между первым ответом сервера и вторым, при условии что клиент после получения первого ответа сразу пошлёт второй запрос.

Comment: Если замерять время между первым ответом сервера и вторым - есть вероятность, что после отправки второго запроса мы заблокируем event loop и второй ответ увидим в js позже, чем он реально придет. В то же время, если сервер написан на чем-нибудь наподобие node.js имеем схожую ситуацию, только с обработкой запроса. С другой стороны это даст примерное представление не в пинге как таковом а в реальной задержки на обработку всей фигни, что происходит=)